# PostgreSQL error: OperationalError: FATAL: role "username" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I got this error When I'm trying to run the Code.

[image: Error]

I searched the site like this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist)

But It couldn't solve my problem.

When I'm trying to create superuser with my username (which is TCOYUKSEL) , It create another one with "tcoyuksel"

[image: Error]

ozgur.py Line 9  `db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=news")`

ozgur.py Line 73 `get_pop_articles(), str("views"))`

**init**.py  Line 130    `conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)`
  --I didn't do anything with this file--

Comment: Add the queries you are using for creating or altering the role. I already have a hunch.

Comment: Mind case-sensitivity.

Comment: @EsaJokinen  , I tried many queries but simply I can wrote this <br/>

`sudo su - postgres 
CREATE ROLE TCOYUKSEL superuser; 
ALTER ROLE TCOYUKSEL WITH LOGIN;`

Answer (score 5):

The role name is case sensitive, but with your queries it gets translated to lower case `tcoyuksel`,

```
CREATE ROLE TCOYUKSEL superuser;
ALTER ROLE TCOYUKSEL WITH LOGIN;
```

as key words and unquoted identifiers are case insensitive ([4.1.1. Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)).

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or
>   quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of
>   characters in double-quotes (`"`). A delimited identifier is always an
>   identifier, never a key word. So `"select"` could be used to refer to a
>   column or table named “`select`”, whereas an unquoted select would be
>   taken as a key word and would therefore provoke a parse error when
>   used where a table or column name is expected.

You need to use the quotes to bypass the normalization i.e. use `TCOYUKSEL` as *delimited identifier*:

```
CREATE ROLE "TCOYUKSEL" superuser;
ALTER ROLE "TCOYUKSEL" WITH LOGIN;
```

If you run it directly from the command line, you need to double the quotes:

```
postgres "CREATE ROLE ""TCOYUKSEL"" superuser; ALTER ROLE ""TCOYUKSEL"" WITH LOGIN;"
```

Comment: I couldn't save it as image , but It didn't work https://preview.ibb.co/gPWQ2y/hata2.jpg

Comment: Add lines near lines 73, 9 of your `ozgur.py`, and 130 of `__init__.py`. (Edit original question.)

Comment: ok I've added the original question, thanks in advance

Comment: The error is not on line `73` but somewhere near, where the username is passed. More lines required to investigate further.